# Afnetworking error using PUT request with Error 400

Tags: ios, ios5, increment, afnetworking, put

I am trying to increment a data on Parse using PUT request.

```
-(void)requestHit {

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:kHBFParseAPIBaseURLString]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-Application-Id" value:kHBFParseAPIApplicationId];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" value:kHBFParseAPIKey];

[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"Increment",@"__op", [NSNumber numberWithInt:100],@"amount",
                               nil];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];

if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"NSJSONSerialization failed %@", error);
}

NSString *json = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary * params = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys: json, @"hot", nil];


[client putPath:self.shopping.objectId parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed %@", error);
}];
}
```

I'm getting an error code 400. I know 400 means bad URL but I check the URL on safari and I was able to access the website. I was thinking that maybe the dictionary is coded wrong way but have no clue. Here is REST API cURL for the increment on Parse website:

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: DWZFxindnjGtp3SCMmA4iGaYN55dgVDRmobt7mkC" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: QbjhRMhVshPkJmEoDdpS3xAkNOofzLsUBlMBQETU" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"score":{"__op":"Increment","amount":1}}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm
```

Please help~~

Comment: Failed Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x6b9edd0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Shopping/wPHsodI08s, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400}

Answer (score 0):

By default, AFHTTPClient will use AFFormURLParameterEncoding as the way to encode parameter, so you have to set it to AFJSONParameterEncoding

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L473

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ#how-do-i-send-json-parameters-in-my-request

Answer (score 0):

some java web server cannot receive @"__op":@(1) this kind of params, you should manual convert it to @"0" or @"1", this will avoid the 400 error. Just try it.